# How to bring back menus is VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I accidentally disabled the top menu in VirtualBox while in a VM of Windows XP, how do I get them back?

Answer (score 2):

You can go back from full-screen mode in a VirtualBox guest OS by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Note that the main menu bar is hidden in full-screen mode. You can access a popup menu that has the main menu bar's entries (as shown in the 2nd screenshot) by pressing <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.

[image]

[image]

To reenable the Toolbar in the VirtualBox application right-click on the bottom panel and check the checkbox next to *Show Toolbar* as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]